# Exceptions in ASP.NET CORE API not sent to Front

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In the `startup.cs` code I do the following in the  `Configure` method :

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
```

As a result, in my environment is not Development, when calling the API from Postman or even from a dedicated frontend, the error details are not returned.

However the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS` is set to **true** , so I would expect to receive details of the exception.

As a workaround, I had to create my own configuration setting and change the code to  :

```
         if (env.IsDevelopment() || Configuration["DetailedErrors"] == "true")
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
```

Do I really need to do that or am I missing something ?

Comment: `ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS` only affects _startup_ errors. It doesn't, and isn't intended to, magically enable the developer exception page middleware.

Answer (score 1):

According to

> in my environment is not Development,

I understood that you wish to receive a detailed exception in the `production environment`.

if this is the case, you may just replace

```
    if (env.IsDevelopment() || Configuration["DetailedErrors"] == "true")
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
```

with

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

Not critical but the `if condition` became useless I believe so better to get rid of it (as your `ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS` variable is set to true).

Comment: I have tried that. Obviously by removing the condition, errors are returned fine. However if I set the ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS, the errors are STILL returned. I would expect this env variable to have some effect, but it does not seem to change anything.